# Backbone.js collection.at(i).get('person') references to the same model in a loop

Tags: backbone.js

I have

```
data = {
  "name1": "id1"
  , "name2": "id2"
  , "name3": "id3"
  , "name4": "id4"
  , "name5": "id5"
}

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Backbone.Model
})

var myCollection = new MyCollection();

myCollection.fetch({
  success: function(collection, response) {
    var i = 0;

    for (var name in data) {
      if ( !data.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) continue;

      (function(theName) {
        var obj = collection.at(i).get('object');
        obj.id = data[theName];
        obj.displayName = theName;
        collection.at(i).set({"object": obj});
      })(name);
      i++
    }
  }
})
```

The `response` contains

```
[
  null
  , {
    "_id" : "some id"
    , "object": {
      "displayName": "name1"
      , "id": "id1"
    }
  }
  , null
  , {
    "_id" : "some id"
    , "object": {
      "displayName": "name1"
      , "id": "id1"
    }
  }
  , null
]
```

Some of the `null` value is because they does not exist in database. The collection on fetch will create a default model for those `null`, which the same structure, but no `_id`, and properties of `object`  are empty strings.

The problem I have is after the loop, all the models has the same attributes as the last one in `data`, i.e., `name5` and `id5`. I checked `obj` in each iteration, and it was indeed the same object. Thus, for each iteration, all models in the collection is set the same attributes.

Variable `name` in each iteration changes according to `data`, as well as `i` is increased. I also put the iteration inside a closure to make sure the scope is right.

Why Backbone behaves that way?

---

#### Update

It turned out that because of those `null` values in the `response` that made Backbone model behave so weird. I overridden `parse` function in the collection to set default values for the `null` object instead of relying on defaults value of the model, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the code in detail, but I have a hunch. Would this work?

```
myCollection.fetch({
  success: function ( collection, response ) {
    var i = 0;

    for ( var name in data ) {
      (function ( theName, j ) {
        var obj = collection.at( j ).get( 'object' );
        obj.id = data[ theName ];
        obj.displayName = theName;
        collection.at( j ).set({ object: obj });
      }( name, i ));
      i += 1;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the mess (of deleting and undoing), but no, it does not work. I was excited for a moment, then I realized that it was a typo that made it work, but not the way I want.

Comment: Yeah, instead of `var obj = collection.at( j ).get( 'object' );` I put `var obj = collection.at( j );`  This obviously just put the whole model to the attribute `object` of the model, so it works, but not correctly.

Comment: And should your code be

`(function ( theName, j ) { ... } ) ( name, i );` ?

Comment: Ah, I thought closure execution should be `(function (a, b) {...})(c, d)` instead of `(function (a, b){...}(c, d))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
function assign(obj, name){
    obj.id = data[name];
    obj.displayName = name
}
for (var name in data) {
  var obj = collection.at(i).get('object');
  assign(obj, name)
  collection.at(i).set({"object": obj});
  i++
}
```

Hopefully, it works because I am not sure about iteration i :D

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's try again:

```
myCollection.fetch({
    success: function( coll ) {
        _.each( _.keys( data ), function ( name, i ) {
            var obj = _.extend( coll.at( i ).get( 'object' ), {
                id: data[ name ],
                displayName: name
            });
            coll.at( i ).set({ 'object': obj });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It still does not work :( I think it's something with the data the server sent to Backbone. The response contains `null` in some of the index, thus some of the model in the collection has default values, which are empty strings.

I will update my question to include the `response` if it helps any.

Comment: It turned out that because of those `null` values in the `response` that made Backbone model behave so weird. I overridden `parse` function in the collection to set default values to the `null` object instead of relying on defaults value of the model, and it works with your previous answer. Would you mind putting back your previous answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @esente That wouldn't be proper. You solved the issue, so you should post an answer with the solution.

Comment: It would not run without your previous answer though. So I used your answer :)